# Keycloak Theme: Update AngularJS file

Tags: angularjs, keycloak

I created a custom theme based on the base theme and the keycloak theme. I have made some changes to the ftl files and it works fine. Now I want to make some changes to the **realm.js** file. I registered the **realm.js** file in **theme.properties** file `scripts=js/controllers/realm.js`. But when I deploy my custom theme jar file, I don't see the changes made to the **realm.js** file.

When I create a new plain js file with `alert(123);` content and register it in the **theme.properties** file, it works as expected.

Why doesn't it work with angularjs **realm.js** file?

Answer (score 0):

Due to theme caching, changes are not reflected. After pressing Ctrl + F5, all changes work as expected.